# Java NoClassDefFoundError in a simple project

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I'm quite a beginner in Java and I'm getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

error in a really simple Java program in a test class (RomanTest) and I have no idea how to solve the problem.

What can be the cause of the error and how to repair it? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Link for downloading .zip containing my project:
https://ufile.io/f0erfyon

Comment: What command do you use to run the app ?

Comment: And what are you using as the dependency management tool ?

Comment: I have no idea what is dependency management tool and I'm just clicking the green arrow button Run 'RomanTest' to run the project in IntelliJ

Comment: Here, import this repo into your IDE and everything should work https://github.com/klezovics/stackoverflow-arabic-toroman

Comment: You were using an old version of JUnit in this project. It did not have the necessary classes. Tell me if this worked for you.

Comment: I get error: Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for openjdk-17

Comment: Try this https://programmerah.com/how-to-solve-intellij-idea-error-cannot-determine-path-to-tools-jar-library-for-17-cprogram-filesjavajd-38877/

Comment: Thank you, that helped me and now everything works :)
Anyway, I had to install newest release oj IntelliJ IDEA and after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should not work with such outdated version of JUnit.
For example use at least one of the lastest release version of the 4'er junit in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found an answer:

I had to update IntelliJ IDEA to the newest release and use newer version of JUnit. That solved the problem.

Comment: this is not a problem of the IDE